# LinkedIn share post not working and gives error message: 'It's not you it's us, give it another try please.'

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I have a wordpress website https://www.qubeworx.com/ and we have some news posts which we want to share with linkedin. If we click on the share button, we get the error message:

'It's not you it's us, give it another try please.'.

When I have a look at the URL created:

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.qubeworx.com%2Fideal-news%2F

I see that the some post share is working fine on same website.
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.qubeworx.com%2Fjohn-gant-named-president-of-qubeworx%2F

What is going wrong here? How can we change the share link URL so linkedin will accept it?

We tried reading a lot of other helpdesk but non of them seem logic.

Comment: Have you used any plugin or share is by custom code?

Comment: I tried by both plugin and custom.

https://www.qubeworx.com/news/
Some posts are working fine but on some post its throwing error "It's not you it's us, give it another try please.'

Comment: I was getting this issue because of the linkedin server and response.

Comment: That's great you solved it! I think you should post this as an answer, so if any one faces same problem will know this easily.

Answer (score 1):

Linkedin share is working fine now. I have to got to know that it was a server error from Linkedin and it was blocking response from the server.

Comment: I have a same error, what did you do to solve this?

Comment: How did you fix it. ?

Comment: We are getting this error due to the blocked server response. It means some problem with linkedIn severs so it can't load the page you are expecting.